# How to append separate datasets to make a combined stacked dataset in Stata without losing information

Tags: merge, append, stata

I'm trying to merge two datasets from two time periods, time 1 & 2, to make a combined repeated measures dataset. There are some observations in time 1 which do not appear in time 2, as the observations are for participants who dropped out after time 1.

When I use the `append` command in Stata, it appears to drop the observations from time 1 that don't have corresponding data at time 2. It does, however, append observations for new participants who joined at time 2.

I would like to keep the time 1 data of those participants who dropped out, so that I can still use that information in the combined dataset.

How can I tell Stata not to automatically drop these participants?

Thanks,

Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the best way of interesting people in advising you on your problems is to respect those answer your questions. You have been repeatedly advised, even as recently as yesterday, to review https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers and provide the feedback that reflects itself in the reputation scores of those who take the time to help you.

In any event, append does not work as you describe it. If you take the time to work out a small reproducible example, by creating two small datasets, appending them, and then listing the results, you may find the roots of your misunderstanding. Or you will at least be able to provide substantive information from which others can work, should someone be interested in helping you.

Comment: My humblest apologies, William. I'm new to these kinds of forums, and hadn't realised what the expectations upon users are. Thank you for directing me to the guidelines.

Comment: Thank you for having taken the time to respond on this and previous topics.